# Enable VueJS DevTools for Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-nova

I want to inspect the underlying behavior of Laravel Nova(or custom field) and i am trying to enable the devtools. On the top right corner I can see the green icon of VueJS but when i go to the console there is no tab for VueJS

How can i enable it and inspect all the components?

Cheers

Comment: If you click the icon for Vue Devtools, does it give you any information?  You might be compiling your Vue in production mode and not development mode.  Also, I have found that I randomly need to hide and then show the console again to get the Vue tab to show up for me (in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! What actually worked was restarting Chrome. Now i am diving into trying to customize nova and see what is the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding **Vue.config.devtools = true** to MyComponent/resources/js/filed.js, the devtools are available.

Close the console and open again, Make sure your in dev or watch mode.

Answer (score 8):

**Try these Steps:**

```
cd ./vendor/laravel/nova
mv webpack.mix.js.dist webpack.mix.js
npm i
npm run dev
rm -rf node_modules
cd -
php artisan nova:publish
```

Comment: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/frontend.html#vue-devtools

Comment: Read the documentation if you can something!